# ¿Cómo limpiar String de tildes en java?

Tags: java

He probado varios métodos para intentar esto, y ninguno me funcionó. Lo que necesito es un método que limpie palabras de tildes, y otros símbolos como la ñ o la ü. Es decir:

Si recibe la palabra `corrió`, devuelve la palabra `corrio`, o `ñandú`, devuelve `nandu`.

Probé los siguientes métodos encontrados en este sitio y otros y ninguno funciona!

```
private String remove1(String texto) {
    String original = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ";
    // Cadena de caracteres ASCII que reemplazarán los originales.
    String ascii = "AAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYBaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy";
    String output = texto;
    for (int i=0; i<original.length(); i++) {
    // Reemplazamos los caracteres especiales.

        output = output.replace(original.charAt(i), ascii.charAt(i));

    }//for i
```

Probé este otro también:

```
public String deAccent(String str) {
      String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str,  Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
      return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```

Todos me devuelven la misma cadena sin modificarla, ¿Cuál puede ser el error?

También necesitaría remover los signos de puntuación, que solo queden caracteres alfanuméricos al ser leídos de un archivo *.txt*

EDITO, clase completa:
El metodo recibe una lista de archivos(libros) de texto para limpiarlos y agregarlos a un vocabulario implementado en un arbol binario.

```
public boolean procesar()
{

        if (libros.getFirst()==null)
        {
            System.out.println("no hay libro");
            return false;

        }
        else 
        {


        File f;

        for (int i = 0; i < libros.size(); i++) 
        {   
            try {
            Libro l;
            l = (Libro) libros.pollFirst();
            f = l.getFile();
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String ln = br.readLine();

                while(ln!=null)
                {

                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(clean);
                    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
                    {

                        String word = st.nextToken();
                        String clean;
                        clean = remove1(word);


                        Palabra p = new Palabra(clean, l);
                        if (h1.contains(p)==false)
                        {
                        h1.add(p);
                       contador++;    

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Palabra aux = (Palabra) h1.search(p);
                            aux.agregaUno();


                        }

                        //System.out.println(clean);

                    }
                ln = br.readLine();

                }


                }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR AL ABRIR ARCHIVO");

            }
        }
        return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: Yo he usado el primer método que indicas y funciona.

Comment: El segundo método funciona perfecto también... Quizás el error está en otro lado. ¿Podrías generar un ejemplo con datos?

Comment: Creo que en el primero no haces `return output` y lo usas donde necesites la cadena cambiada, porque no te cambia texto, te genera otra cambiada que es la variable `output`.

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo mostrando que funciona bien http://rextester.com/JLEOH16760

Comment: Todavía no logro hacerlo funcionar, si pruebo el metodo solo, funciona, pero en mi programa no! edito y agrego el codigo de la clase entera a ver si alguien me puede ayudar!
Gracias

Comment: @JuliánLópezScala revisa la codificación configurada en el editor de código que estés usando

Comment: Reporto también que realizando pruebas con el primer método obtengo la funcionalidad esperada.

Answer (score 10):

Para quitar los acentos puedes usar la clase [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) de Apache Commons lang3.

Usando esta clase, tienes el método [stripAccents](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents-java.lang.String-), el cual, en su definición, pone lo siguiente:

> Removes diacritics (~= accents) from a string. The case will not be altered.
>
> For instance, 'à' will be replaced by 'a'.

Lo que viene a decir:

> Elimina diacríticos (~ = acentos) de una cadena. El caso no será alterado.
>
> Por ejemplo, 'à' será reemplazado por 'a'.

Comment: Estas son las palabras que ingreso y esto es lo que me devuelve, nose porque ningun metodo que intento me funciona (y si esta bien codificado)

saltó
corrió
corría
céluñar
ñandú

-----
corri� - 1 corr�a - 1 c�lu�ar - 1 salt� - 1 �and� - 1

------

(Los numeros y guinoes los agregue yo, posee un contador de frecuencias tambien)

Comment: @JuliánLópezScala Puede ser que tengas el IDE configurado para una codificación distinta. A mí una vez me pasaba algo parecido en eclipse porque la consola estaba en una codificación distinta al IDE (UTF y Windows 1252).

Comment: Edito con el codigo de la clase completa, posiblemente algo este haciendo mal y no logro darme cuenta.
Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Por si alguien aún necesita un método que haga esto, el segundo método que mencionó Julián me ha servido mucho a mí, solo que un poquito diferente:

```
public static String quitaDiacriticos(String s) {
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
    return s;
}
```

Recomendaría acoplarlo al final con un s.toLowerCase()

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar este método usando Normalizer y un REGEX:

```
String original = "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ";
String cadenaNormalize = Normalizer.normalize(original, Normalizer.Form.NFD);   
String cadenaSinAcentos = cadenaNormalize.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println("Resultado: " + cadenaSinAcentos);
```

Teniendo como resultado:

```
Resultado: AAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyy
```

Existe una **[respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3322174/250260)** de @ErikRobertson en

Comment: Me parece que es prácticamente el mismo método que el que publicó el autor (sólo que no acepta utf-8 como sí lo haría `\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}` o `\p{M}` como sugiere al final).

Comment: Creo que deberías editarla @Elenasys. Con el comentario anterior, me refería a este comportamiento: http://rextester.com/KQGF27223 .. Me parece importante tratar de que cualquier código permita i18n (-1).

Answer (score 2):

te muestro una forma de limpiar tildes u otros caracteres especiales.

```
public static String limpiarAcentos(String cadena) {
    String limpio =null;
    if (cadena !=null) {
        String valor = cadena;
        valor = valor.toUpperCase();
        // Normalizar texto para eliminar acentos, dieresis, cedillas y tildes
        limpio = Normalizer.normalize(valor, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        // Quitar caracteres no ASCII excepto la enie, interrogacion que abre, exclamacion que abre, grados, U con dieresis.
        limpio = limpio.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}(N\u0303)(n\u0303)(\u00A1)(\u00BF)(\u00B0)(U\u0308)(u\u0308)]", "");
        // Regresar a la forma compuesta, para poder comparar la enie con la tabla de valores
        limpio = Normalizer.normalize(limpio, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
    }
    return limpio;
}
```

Pudes agregar los caracteres a limpiar.

Answer (score -1):

Esta función por ejemplo normaliza los tildes y ademas reemplaza todo lo que no sea a-z, A-Z o número por nada

```
public static String normalizeString(String str){
 str=Normalizer.normalize(str,Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
 return str.replaceAll("[^a-z,^A-Z,^0-9]", "");
}
```

Comment: Esto eliminaría otros caracteres como espacios, signos de puntuación, etc... Además, la expresión regular está mal.

Answer (score -1):

La respuesta de [Ventur](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6811/ventur) funciona muy bien en Java, para los que usen kotlin, este seria el método adaptado.

```
fun clearAccents(sequence: String): String {
    var cleanedString: String?
    var valor: String = sequence
    valor = valor.toUpperCase()
    // Normalizar el texto para eliminar acentos, dieresis, cedillas(ç, ş, etc.) y tildes
    cleanedString = Normalizer.normalize(valor, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    // Quitar caracteres no ASCII excepto la enie, interrogacion que abre, exclamacion que abre, grados, U con dieresis.
    cleanedString = cleanedString.replace("[^\\p{ASCII}(N\u0303)(n\u0303)(\u00A1)(\u00BF)(\u00B0)(U\u0308)(u\u0308)]".toRegex(), "")
    // Regresar a la forma compuesta, para poder comparar la enie con la tabla de valores
    cleanedString = Normalizer.normalize(cleanedString, Normalizer.Form.NFC)
    return cleanedString
}
```

Comment: puedes explicar lo que hace tu método?