# Spring Example Matcher. ¿Cómo indicar que la búsqueda no sea sensitiva a tildes?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, spring, spring-boot, tildes

Pongamos como ejemplo un servicio rest en el que nos proporcionan el nombre de una persona y se devuelven las características de las que el nombre esté contenido en los nombres almacenados en base de datos. Poniendo ignoreCase() consigo que no sea sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, ¿cómo puedo conseguir que no sea sensible a tildes? Por ejemplo, si en el servicio se nos indica tanto "Raul" cómo "Raúl" debería devolver sus características, pero solo nos la devuelve si se indica exactamente como en base de datos, es decir, con la tilde. Pongo la parte del código por si alguien me puede indicar como completar para que no sea sensible a tildes. Gracias de antemano.

```
Persona persona = mapper.map(iPersonaGeoJson, Persona.class);

ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues().withMatcher("nombre", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.contains().ignoreCase());

List<Persona> personas = personaRepositoryInterface.findAll(Example.of(persona, matcher));
```

Comment: No estoy muy seguro que te sirva, pero acá hay un link con un problema parecido: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31178/c%C3%B3mo-limpiar-string-de-tildes-en-java

Comment: Hola Pedro, muchas gracias. La respuesta sería muy útil si tuviera que tratar String que no vinieran de base de datos, pero en este caso no es así. Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Desde java7 puedes utilizar `Collator` que es específicamente un comparador para lenguaje natural, esto quiere decir que es más adecuado a situaciones de escritura como el que planteas, utilizando el método `compare` que retorna `0` si la cadena es igual, te dejo el ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena1 = "Raul";
    String cadena2 = "ràúl";

    final Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();

    // Se configura por estrategias y con NO_DECOMPOSITION es para comparar sin tener en cuenta los acentos.
    collator.setStrength(Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION);

    System.out.println(collator.compare(cadena1, cadena2));
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta pero no es exactamente lo que busco, ya que luego hago uso de un repositorio Spring JPA que es el que hace la búsqueda de entre todos los nombres y quiero pasarle el matcher ya preparado para ignorar acentos. Añado el código siguiente por si te sirve para hacerte una idea. Lo del Collator ya tenía una idea pero no quiero comparar dos strings que ya tengo, sino uno que viene de base de datos. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Creo que con ´ExampleMatcher´ no tienes esa posibilidad, he intentado ver una posible solución y solo se me ocurre utilizar una `NativeQuery` pero tendrías el inconveniente que  el SQL seria especifico a la base de datos que utilices.

Comment: Definitivamente yo también creo que no es posible, lo del Native Query es una posibilidad y lo utilizo en otras consultas, voy a valorar si me merece la pena o no. Gracias!!!

Comment: Otras soluciones que se me ocurre es una vista materializada donde el nombre este normalizado o agregar una columna con el nombre normalizado para hacer la consulta sobre esta.